# Will firebase switch to Blaze Plan from Spark Plan automatically as soon as the limits are exhausted?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Will Firebase switch to Blaze Plan from Spark Plan automatically as soon as the Spark Plan limits are exhausted or will it continue spark plan and notify about the limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually. The blaze plan includes all the free features of the spark plan, so if you are ready to pay for extra usage, you may switch in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Will Firebase switch to Blaze Plan from Spark Plan automatically?

No, it won't. Firebase quotas are reset daily at midnight (Pacific time). According to your timezone, it may actually be in the middle of the day. So if you reach the daily limitation, you need to wait until the "next" day.

Besides that, you'll get an exception when you reach the daily limit.

As @Rediska mentioned in his answer, to switch to the Spark plan you need to do it yourself. That's **not** an automatic switch.